# Firefox Performance Call Tree Samples breakdown shows zero

Tags: firefox-developer-tools, web-performance

According to the third picture [on the Firefox devtools documentation page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Performance/Call_Tree), the break down of "samples" should show a "samples" value for each row.

When I run Firefox devtools *all* break down rows shows "0" for the "samples" value - is this an error? Should the break down not show any values for "Samples"? Am I doing something wrong here?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to have been a limitation of the invert algorithm since the panel's beginnings. Disabling Invert Call Tree in the profiler options shows the samples and self time/cost correctly.

There is a new profiler in the works that has a much more advanced Call Tree. 
It can be installed from here: http://profiler.firefox.com/

Thanks to [Harald Kirschner](https://discourse.mozilla.org/u/digitarald) and [Julien Wajsberg](https://discourse.mozilla.org/u/julienw) for the help!